# How to append to a pointer array in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have an array of pointers to structs and I'm trying to find a way to fill the first NULL pointer in an array with a new pointer to a struct. i.e. I want to add a new element onto the end of an array.
I tried a for loop like this:

```
struct **structs;

int i;
for(i = 0; i < no_of_pointers; i++) {
        if (structs[i] == NULL) {
              structs[i] = &struct;
        }
}
```

In theory, this would go through the array and when it finds a null pointer it would initialise it. I realise now that it would initialise all null pointers, not just the first, but when I run it it doesn't even do that. I've tried a while loop with the condition while(structs[i] != NULL) and that just goes on forever, making me think that the issue is with how I'm using NULL.
What is the correct way to add a new element to an array of this kind?
Is there some function like append(structs, struct) that I don't know of?
Thanks!

Comment: You *have* allocated `structs` before this? You *have* initialized each pointer in the "array" to `NULL`? If you're using `malloc` it will **not** initialize the memory it allocate for you.

Comment: How do you initialize `structs` and `no_of_pointers`?

Comment: Note that `struct` is a keyword and cannot be used as a variable name.  This means we aren't looking at your real code, which means there may be other extra errors in the code.  It's best, in general, to show an extract from your real code rather than to misparaphrase it.

Comment: Sorry! I was just cutting out unimportant stuff to get to the point. Imagine no_of_pointers has been previously set and there's a preprocessor thingy saying struct struct { etc. etc. In this case, struct is a type of struct - sorry, a bit confusing.

Comment: This isn't referring to any code in particular - I'm just trying to understand the concept of how you add elements to the end of an array. The program I'm writing where I need to understand this is far too monstrous to copy-paste into here.

Comment: You should make You might a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: If you want to stop after finding the first null pointer you could just add break; after structs[i] = &struct; or raise a flag and add that flag to the for condition.

Answer (score 3):

The length of an array in C is fixed, you cannot change it after you defined an array, which means you cannot add an element to the end of an array. However, unless you defined a constant array, you could assign new values to elements of an array. According to your question description, I believe this is what you want.

Also note that, as other already pointed it out in comments, `struct` is a keyword of C, therefore

1. you cannot use it as a type name (as you did in `struct **structs`)
2. you also cannot use it as a variable name (as you did in `structs[i] = &struct;`)

Here is one way to do it:

1. define an array properly

   ```
   struct struct_foo **structp;

   structp = malloc (no_of_elements * sizeof(*structp));
   if (structp == NULL) {
           /* error handle */
   }
   ```

   Note, at here the elements of `structp` is not initialized, you need to initialize them properly. That is what we are going to do in step 2.
2. do something with `structp`, maybe initialize all its elements to `NULL` or some no-`NULL` value
3. find the first no-`NULL` element in `structp`, and assign it a new value

   ```
   struct struct_foo foo;

   for (i = 0; i < no_of_elements; i++) {
           if (structp[i] == NULL) {
                   structp[i] = &foo;
                   break;
           }
   }
   ```

   Note that this `foo` also is uninitialized, you may want to initialize it first, or you could initialize it later.

Comment: You can use the `reallocarray()` function to resize `structs`, such that a new variable where `sizeof(x) == sizeof(struct)` may be stored there. See my answer for more information

Answer (score 0):

According to `man malloc`:

```c
       void *malloc(size_t size);
       void free(void *ptr);
       void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);
       void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
       void *reallocarray(void *ptr, size_t nmemb, size_t size);

...

    The reallocarray() function  changes  the  size  of  the  memory  block
    pointed  to  by  ptr to be large enough for an array of nmemb elements,
    each of which is size bytes.  It is equivalent to the call

           realloc(ptr, nmemb * size);
```

Try implementing a system like this

```c
struct **structs;

int new_struct() {
    static int i = 0; // index of last allocated struct

    i++;
    struct *structp = malloc(sizeof(struct)); // new structure
    // initialize structp here

    reallocarray(structs, i, sizeof(struct));
    structs[i] = structp;

    return i; // use structs[index] to get
}
```

Then you may invoke `new_struct()`, which resizes the `structs` array and appends `structp` to it. The important part is that

- a) `create_struct` returns the index of the newly created struct, and
- b) it stores a `static int i`, which keeps track of the size of the `structs`.